# Mailer not being loaded in Rake Tasks with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, rake-task, mailer

I am trying to send a Mail using a Rake Task. It works fine in development environment, but not in staging.

It keeps giving following error-
uninitialized constant ReservationMailer

Any help is appreciated.

lib/tasks/reminders.rake

```
namespace :reservations do
  desc 'send reservation reminder mail to customers'
  task :reminder => :environment do
    reservations = Reservation.tomorrow
    reservations.each { |reservation| reservation.send_reservation_reminder_mail }
  end
end
```

app/models/reservation.rb

```
 class Reservation
   include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Timestamps::Short

   ...

   def send_reservation_reminder_mail
     ::ReservationMailer.customer_reservation_reminder(self).deliver
   end
 end
```

app/mailers/reservation_mailer.rb

```
class ReservationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def customer_reservation_reminder(reservation)
    mail to: reservation.customer.email, subject: 'Reminder'
  end
end
```

Comment: please provide classes and file name(including path) which you are using to find the error...there is no way anybody can find the answer with only this much information...

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have a misspelling name either on the class name, or on the filename, thus rails cannot find the Mailer. another way to test it, is boot up a rails c and type ReservationMailer to see if the constant is there or not.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no spelling mistake. I can find the ReservationMailer in 'rails console'. I guess this is some issue with rake tasks + mongoid.

Comment: Also if there was a spelling mistake, it would not have worked in any environment. :)